# Connection string with database

Tags: c#, mysql, rest, wcf, server

I have a client server application. I have a database and some logic written in WCF. For example, I have a restaraunt table (I implemented get, post, put, delete). However, there is an Id_Res field in my table, I wanted to implement it as follows. In the browser I enter the name of the restaurant, it is saved in the database, then the restaurant names are imported from the database into the array or Array List, on the basis of this I create Id_Cus and enter it into the database again.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;
using WcfRestFullService.Model;

namespace WcfRestFullService
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IRestaraunt" in both code and config file together.
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IRestaraunt
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "/GetAllRestaraunts/")]//ok
        List<restaraunt> GetAllRestaraunts();

        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
         ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
         UriTemplate = "/RestarautDetails/{Id_Res}")]
        restaraunt RestarauntDetails(String Id_Res);

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "DELETE", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
         RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
         BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
        void DeleteRestaraunt(String Id_Res);

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
         RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
         //BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
         UriTemplate = "/InsertRestaraunt/")]//problem
        void InsertRestaraunt(restaraunt restarauntDataContract);

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "PUT", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
         RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
         //BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
         UriTemplate = "/UpdateRestaraunt/")]//problem
        void UpdateRestaraunt(restaraunt restarauntDataContract);
    }
}
```

SVC file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;
using WcfRestFullService.Model;

namespace WcfRestFullService
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "Restaraunt" in code, svc and config file together.
    // NOTE: In order to launch WCF Test Client for testing this service, please select Restaraunt.svc or Restaraunt.svc.cs at the Solution Explorer and start debugging.
    public class Restaraunt : IRestaraunt
    {
        MySQLEntities dc;
        public void DeleteRestaraunt(string Id_Res)
        {
            int k = Convert.ToInt32(Id_Res);
            restaraunt res = (from n in dc.restaraunts
                         where n.Id_Res == k
                         select n).Include(c => c.orders).Include(c => c.dishes).ToList().First();

            dc.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
            dc.restaraunts.Remove(res);
            dc.SaveChanges();
        }


        public List<restaraunt> GetAllRestaraunts()
        {
            var query = (from a in dc.restaraunts
                         select a).Distinct();

            List<restaraunt> RestarauntsList = new List<restaraunt>();

            query.ToList().ForEach(x =>
            {
                RestarauntsList.Add(new restaraunt
                {
                    Id_Res = x.Id_Res,
                    Name_Res=x.Name_Res,
                    Phone_Res=x.Phone_Res,
                    Dishes_Res=x.Dishes_Res,
                    Adress_Res=x.Adress_Res,
                    Email_Res=x.Email_Res,
                    WebSite_Res=x.WebSite_Res,
                    Rating_Res=x.Rating_Res
                });
            });
            return RestarauntsList;
        }

        public void InsertRestaraunt(restaraunt restarauntDataContract)
        {
            restaraunt res = new restaraunt(); 
            order ord = new order();
            customer cust = new customer();
           // ArrayList a1 = new ArrayList { "fish", "meet", "drinks" };
            //a1.Add(fish);
            ord.Name_Dis = "Any Food";
            {
                res.Id_Res = restarauntDataContract.Id_Res;
                res.Name_Res = restarauntDataContract.Name_Res;
                res.Phone_Res = restarauntDataContract.Phone_Res;
                res.Dishes_Res = restarauntDataContract.Dishes_Res;
                res.Adress_Res = restarauntDataContract.Adress_Res;
                res.Email_Res = restarauntDataContract.Email_Res;
                res.WebSite_Res = restarauntDataContract.WebSite_Res;
                res.Rating_Res = restarauntDataContract.Rating_Res;
            }
            dc.restaraunts.Add(res);
            dc.SaveChanges();

            int k = Convert.ToInt32(res.Id_Res);
            restaraunt restFromDb = (from n in dc.restaraunts
                                   where n.Id_Res == k
                                   select n).Include(c => c.orders).Include(c => c.dishes).First();
        }

        public restaraunt RestarauntDetails(string Id_Res)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void UpdateRestaraunt(restaraunt restarauntDataContract)
        {
            int k = Convert.ToInt32(restarauntDataContract.Id_Res);
            restaraunt res = dc.restaraunts.Where(n => n.Id_Res == k).FirstOrDefault();

            res.Id_Res = restarauntDataContract.Id_Res;
            res.Name_Res = restarauntDataContract.Name_Res;
            res.Phone_Res = restarauntDataContract.Phone_Res;
            res.Dishes_Res = restarauntDataContract.Dishes_Res;
            res.Adress_Res = restarauntDataContract.Adress_Res;
            res.Email_Res = restarauntDataContract.Email_Res;
            res.WebSite_Res = restarauntDataContract.WebSite_Res;
            res.Rating_Res = restarauntDataContract.Rating_Res;

            dc.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

As far as I understand, I need to configure the connection string in the SVC file. But since it is inherited, I can’t register the connection to the database. I tried to implement the connection string through a separate class, but I still don’t understand how to activate it correctly in the interface.

```
class DBUtils
    {
        public static MySqlConnection GetDBConnection()
        {
            string host = "localhost";//192.168.205.130
            int port = 3306;
            string database = "simplehr";
            string username = "root";//
            string password = "l10ksfnq5h2c";//

            return DBMySQLUtils.GetDBConnection(host, port, database, username, password);
        }
    }
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace Tutorial.SqlConn
{
    class DBMySQLUtils
    {
        public static MySqlConnection
               GetDBConnection(string host, int port, string database, string username, string password)
        {
            // Connection String.
            String connString = "Server=" + host + ";Database=" + database
                + ";port=" + port + ";User Id=" + username + ";password=" + password;

            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connString);

            return conn;
        }
    }
}
```

If I understand everything correctly, then I only need the connection string for the InsertRestaraunt (POST method) function

I would be grateful if you would tell me how to implement a connection string in WCF

Comment: With entity there is a mapping that exists between the database and the classes in c#.  So when you do a query of the database you query the classes to get the data.  So you have your database dc and a table that is implemented as List<Restaurant> . So to get the restaurants you do dc.restaraunts.  Distinct will only work if you implement IEqualable<Restaurant>.  So instead you can do following : dc.restaraunts.GroupBy(x => x.Id).Select(x => x.First()).ToList()

Comment: okey, I'll try. However, this is not quite what I wanted to know. You have reviewed the Getallrestaraunt method. pay attention to the InsertRestaraunt method.

Comment: The question is as follows. I safely fill out my entire table (except for Id_Cus). I would like to implement the following - the user enters all the data except Id_Res (for example, he enters all the data, including Name_Res). it all went to the db. Then I want to process Id_Cus myself, namely: take all the names of the restaurants and load them into an array, then assign each one their own identifier. then fill in the Id_Cus field with these identifiers. The problem is that when I try to get the names of restaurants, I need a connection string to the database. maybe you could tell?

Comment: You are using Entity which automatically has a connection to the database.  You do not need a 2nd connection.  May be you want a dictionary : Dictionary<string,string> dict = dc.restuaraunts.GroupBy(x => x.Name_Res, y => y.Id).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());

Comment: Dictionary may be a really good idea, but I have a question. 1) Group by is the usual grouping (Id_Cus by Name_Res). In turn, I do not have to do this at all. I want to turn to the Name_Res field, then for example, using the dictionary, set each restaurant to its Id_Res. I used your advice, but I don’t quite understand how I can only add value to Id_Cus
I attach the code below

Comment: Dictionary<string, int> dict = dc.restaraunts.GroupBy(x => x.Name_Res, y => y.Id_Res)
                                                             .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());

Comment: dict[name].Id = Id.  The dictionary must use the name like in my code and then set the Id.